# Problems whie compiling turtlebot packages

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm compiling some turtlebot packages and I get this error while compiling turtlebot_self_filter:

```
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package turtlebot_self_filter
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build
  cd build && make -l4
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/laser_footprint_filter
  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual@libmysqlclient_16'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/laser_footprint_filter] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_footprint_filter.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_self_filter/build'
```

I algo get a similar error while trying to execute turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch:

```
[ERROR] [1339682184.543002698]: Failed to load nodelet [/pointcloud_throttle] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle]: Failed to load library /home/turtlebot/ros_electric/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/lib/libcloud_to_scan.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1339682184.558845604]: Service call failed!
```

It looks like both things lead to the same: __cxa_pure_virtual@libmysqlclient_16

Some hint on that?

chers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36516/problems-whie-compiling-turtlebot-packages/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient16
```

If using ubuntu/debian, make sure to check that the update repositories are enabled by checking that /etc/apt/sources.list has:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates universe main multiverse
```

Or by checking in Synaptic in settings>repositores>updates>recommended updates checkbox.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2012-06-15**:
it worked. Thanks!

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-06-21**:
Worked for me too in a different context. Thanks!

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-10-11**:
What version of libmysqlclient16 do you have? I've it installed, but still am receiving the dreaded undefined "__cxa_pure_virtual@libmysqlclient_16".

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2012-10-30**:
it worked. Thanks!